# Какие операции делают итераторы std::vector недопустимыми?

Tags: c++

Какими операциями над vector можно сделать его итератор недопустимым?

Comment: Вставкой, удалением. Словом, изменением самого хранилища. Удалением самого вектора :) Понятно, что еще - операциями над итератором - типа `--` для `v.begin()`.

Comment: Открываете [мануал](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), по очереди проверяете каждый неконстантный метод, ищете в описаниях методов фразу *"iterators are invalidated"* и условия, когда это происходит.